# Fired due to lack of motivation

Tags: motivation, depression

So, I was fired a few weeks ago after being in place for ten months.

I was told that my manager had come in to see me for a chat, and he said "It's not good news, the client wants to reduce the team size by one, and they've picked you, I have to take your pass and escort you out". So he did.

The real reason came over the phone later: "The client reported to us your job performance was not satisfactory. Hence we terminated your placement". Unsurprisingly they haven't been forthcoming with any more work offers.

To be honest, I haven't been feeling 100% for a while as within the last five months my partner chose to end a long term >5 years relationship and just disappeared from my life with a new boyfriend. This has affected me in several ways, general despondency about life and lack of direction, but primarily motivation.

I've been trying hard but I've probably been able to give only 2-3 out of 5 when it comes to work. Of course I've always given 100% when dealing with the users and client staff, but objectively I feel that I haven't been so proactive in dealing with issues where I'm expected to take the initiative, or not properly prioritising my workload.

Right now, not sure what the next steps are, have half-heartedly been applying for jobs, but my mind isn't in it. Applied for a masters at several local universities, but was unsuccessful for every one. Have tried counselling but the TL;DR version of that was that sometimes relationships work out and sometimes they don't, snap out of it and move on, blah blah. I did try that, but nobody seems interested in me in that way whatsoever.

Additionally I've always been quite introverted and as I'd moved several hours to her city, came with a ready made group of her friends to socialise with. Of course they have to choose which side to take and I don't begrudge them not talking to me. So I have nobody to talk to either. I

I realise that it's not a good place to be with no job, no social life, no friends and your day consists of getting up when you feel like it and watching daytime TV, evening TV and then going to bed. *How can I make progress on improving my life?* I need advice and suggestions of how to snap out of this, otherwise before I know it a year will have passed and I'm still in the same situation...

Comment: Seems like you need relational advise not workplace advise. You need to move on. You need to find new friends. Find a hobby or something your passionate about. Lean into it very hard. Look for social groups or activities, there are always plenty of these going on if you look in the right place. Your not looking for a new relationship right now. Your trying to figure out who you are as an individual. So try as many different activities as you can to figure it out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about depression not navigating the workplace.

Answer (score 9):

There isn't really a question here (crtl + f "?" yields no results) but I feel like after reading the post I understand what you are trying to communicate.

It sounds like you're suffering from burnout and/or depression and were fired from it taking over your life, which is understandable. This is a very difficult position to be in and you most likely wont get the help you need from the stack exchange. I suggest looking into talking to a mental health professional in the near future.

There is no easy way to dig yourself out of a hole like this, and doing so requires a lot of grit. I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

Set a list of priorities.

Your health and wellbeing first.
See a psychologist, life coach or priest if it feels too dark and you don't enjoy anything. Talk to someone. There's plenty of people that want to help.
Take some time for you. Walk, watch movies, assemble miniature, crochet, whatever you like.
Keep sane habits. No need to go vegan or hermit,  but don't go over the top on junk food, alcohol, drugs, porn or Fortnite. It's an easy trap at times like this.
Keep showering everyday. Call your mom or sibling. Cousins.

Monetary stability next.
Find another job. Yeah it might need to be flipping burgers, if you're stuck, but a crappy job for a while is better than going downhill from here. Most of NA at the moment have a good market for job-seeker, just accept something don't be picky.

Then, when you feel better and have some energy, consider getting a good job back, getting on the dating scene or starting your business.

Take care.
(The whole q and a are probably OT, but I don't care. Take care of YOU, is what I mean)

Answer (score 3):

Part of me wants to mark the question as being closed... because it's not a question.

But the other part of me feels bad and figures I should try to offer some help.  So I will.

Here's the checklist:

**Start an exercise routine each day.**  Doesn't matter if that's walking/jogging/running, if it's swimming, if it's hiking, if it's a sport.  Choose anything that both gets you outside and gets your endorphins pumping.  [Vitamin D is often called the Sunshine Vitamin](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/how-to-increase-vitamin-d), because the sun is one of the best sources for it - and [low levels of Vitamin D are often associated with depression.](https://bmcpsychiatry.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-244X-12-38)  And the reason you want an exercise at least vigorous enough for endorphins is because endorphins help reduce emotional stress.  There's a reason there's the term 'Runners High' - [because endorphins are a natural, wonderful way to keep your brain running clean.](https://www.goodtherapy.org/blog/psychpedia/endorphins)  On a personal level, I've been inconsistently going on jogs, and I can tell just from how I feel whether I've jogged that day.  My brain seems cluttered, slow, bogged down, and stressed on the days I don't go out.  The days I do?  I feel awesome (if possibly a bit tired) for the rest of the day.

**Next, find something to do.**  Ideally, you're after something that has a social component, has a tangible affect, and provides a sense of purpose.  Humans are a social species.  [Even introverts need *some* social component](https://www.businessinsider.com/what-its-like-to-be-an-introvert-and-what-everyone-gets-wrong-2018-5), even if it's not the same level as everyone else.  If you're finding this is a problem, shoot for something structured.  It's a lot easier to talk with people if you're working under a specific framework.  For instance, it's a lot easier to chat with a stranger if you're playing a board game with them than if you're simply sitting waiting for a bus.  The reason you want a tangible affect is so that you can get a sense of accomplishment from your efforts.  And finally, having a sense of purpose gives you drive towards moving forward.  It doesn't have to be your *sole* focus, but right now, part of the reason you're depressed is likely that you're purposeless.  I mean, you wake up, watch tv, eat, watch tv, and go back to sleep - there's no purpose there.

**[Find a job - any job.](https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2014/06/the-mental-health-consequences-of-unemployment/372449/)**  It doesn't have to be glorious.  It doesn't have to be a career.  It just has to be something that gives your day some additional structure as well as giving you a sense of being productive and useful.  Plus, money is good.  Doesn't matter if you don't think you'll have the job for more than a year or even more than a few months, take it.

**Finally, The Size Of The Step Doesn't Matter.**  You don't have to fix everything today.  Or this week.  Or this month.  What you *do* have to do is keep chipping away and improving every time you can.  Maybe you go out and get a job at McDonalds and walk a block today.  Awesome!  Tomorrow, before work, walk a few more and maybe compliment a coworker before your shift begins.  It's only when you try to look at everything *as a whole* that stuff starts to seem impossible.